# EF Core for CosmosDB entity and container mapping

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on a .NET Core 6 application Hot Chocolate GraphQL application, and connecting to Azure CosmosDB using `Micorosft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos`.

My container name is named `auditlog`:

[image]

I have defined an entity like this:

[image]

And lastly, I defined my DataContext like this:

[image]

However, for some reason I can't query `AuditLog`. `ToContainer` is not working. I need to change the entity class name to `auditlog` and that's the only time it will work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) It's really important to provide properly formatted text, for many reasons outlined in the meta post I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

> connecting to Azure CosmosDB using `Micorosft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos`

**Below are the steps I followed:**

- The database context for an application is represented by `EmployeeDbContext`, which is derived from `DbContext`.
- The collection of **Employee** entities is denoted by `DbSet<Employee> Employees"`
- Set up the Cosmos DB connection in `OnConfiguring()` by providing the connection string and the database name.
- The mapping between the **Employee** entity and the **Employees** Cosmos DB container is defined in   `OnModelCreating()`.
- Additionally, `OnModelCreating()` states that the partition key relies on the **id** attribute.
- Created an instance of `EmployeeDbContext` in the **Main** method.
- `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` checks to see if the database and container have been created.
- To the **Employees** Db Set, create a new `Employee` object.
- Use `dbContext.SaveChanges()` to save database changes.

**Below Is the code I tried with:**

```cs
public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionString = "*****";
        var databaseName = "EmployeeDb";

        optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
        connectionString,
        databaseName);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToContainer("Employees").HasPartitionKey(e => e.id);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using var dbContext = new EmployeeDbContext();
        try
        {
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                FirstName = "Pavan",
                LastName = "Balaji",
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1998, 7, 28)
            };

            dbContext.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Employee added successfully.");

            var employees = dbContext.Employees.ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("List of Employees:");
            
            foreach (var employee in employees)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ID: {employee.id}, Name: {employee.FirstName} {employee.LastName}, DOB: {employee.DateOfBirth}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
In Console:

```
Employee added successfully.
List of Employees:
ID: a18857c5-37f0-477a-be62-b64f3ad60039, Name: Pavan Balaji, DOB: 7/28/1998 12:00:00 AM
```

After running `SELECT * FROM c`:

```js
[
    {
        "id": "a18857c5-37f0-477a-be62-b64f3ad60039",
        "DateOfBirth": "1998-07-28T00:00:00",
        "Discriminator": "Employee",
        "FirstName": "Pavan",
        "LastName": "Balaji"
    }
]
```